# Why does WCF service not auto-close the session when InstanceContextMode = Per Call?

Tags: c#, wcf, session

**Background**

I'm playing around with WCF instance context modes to learn how they function in different scenarios. I have the default service set to PerCall. By default I just mean when you create a WCF Service Library it creates a bunch of default code. That's the code I'm working with -- very very simple service. I can call the service just fine from a simple client. But if I leave the client alone and don't press anything for about 10 or 15 mins, and then I try to make another call, I get a message telling me that "The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity."

Here is the full message:

[image]

This is due to the way that I'm handling the proxy on the client side. I never close it. My proxy is just a public class-level variable that I re-use as long as it's not faulted.

**So here is my question:**

Why is the WCF service creating a session at all? I'd think that since the instance context mode is set to PerCall that it wouldn't need a session. And that if it did need a session that it would just close the session after each call. Even though they're coming from the same proxy.

To be clear: I'm not intentionally using any session-specific features. I literally just created a new WCF Service library and set the context mode to PerCall, leaving in all the default operations and such. This is as vanilla a service as it gets.

Comment: What bindings do you use? Do you reinitialize the client for each new call?

Answer (score 0):

That message is about security, not service lifetime. You can have a security context that spans many services of many different lifetime types, but if that security context breaks down (e.g. you haven't renewed your token in a while) you're going to see the error you're seeing regardless of service lifetime settings.

Using PerSession lifetime services just mean that you'd get your own specific instance that stays alive while that session is alive. This is not necessarily tied to security. PerSession services allow you to more easily maintain state for session based scenarios. That said, there are many scaling pitfalls with PerSession services; just be aware they are not necessarily the answer for every scenario.